# Novel To Venus In A Flying Boat

Tags: story-identification, novel

As a boy in the 1960s, I recall reading a novel (possibly a juvenile) in which the heroes (British I think but can't swear to it) travel to Venus in a ship designed to land on water - a kind of flying boat in space. This is to enable it to land on what was then expected to be a "wet Venus" with at any rate more water than land surface.

As  I recall they reach Venus to find an Earthman already there. He is described as knowing nothing about the rights of the individual, so was presumably supposed to be a Russian or similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be [Operation Springboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DWBKA36) by John Ball.

This juvenile was originally published in 1958 which fits the timeframe given in the question, and the Amazon link shows the cover with a flying boat.

The summary on the link may jog some additional memories.

> Chester Pawling, keenly interested in space travel, is invited to work at a base in the South Pacific where the great scientist, Dr. Havensson, is conducting highly secret experiments. That is just the beginning of a grand adventure that fulfils Chester’s dream of traveling into space. But it is not simple or safe. A rival national group has launched a rocket ship and a dangerous space race has begun. Chester, who is physically handicapped, gets more than one chance to prove that he is as capable as any other member of the crew.

Will try to add more information when back on my computer

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure this is it. The date fits (I was ten then and just getting into sf in a big way) and that cover rings a bell.

Comment: I note that it has also been published as "Operation Space", and I have a feeling that this was the title under which I read it. But it's the same story so you're still right.